# audio record through ear phone in android?

Tags: android, audio

I want to record user's singing for karaoke. I used audio recorder API of android to record audio. My requirement is to record only user's singing for karaoke, I do not want karaoke getting mixed with user's singing. So I used ear phone to listen to karaoke and record user's singing through ear phone. My problem is, in some of the device karoake gets mixed with users singing. Also audio quality is very bad. I'm using MIC audio source with 8000 frequency and channel in mono. I got little success with audio source camcoder but recorded audio is of  low quality. Is there any way to improve audio quality? Also is camcoder is supported in all device? Is there any other way to record only users singing?. Your response will be helpful. Thank you.